# RelativeLayout id references

Tags: android, android-layout

These two views are inside of `RelativeLayout`. The IDE throws an error there is no `@id/et_pass`, but if I set `@+id/et_pass` it is OK. Why is that?

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/devider_zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/et_pass" <!-- Error is here -->
    android:src="@drawable/registration_line" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/devider_first"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:ems="8"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/register_layout_edittext_margin_top"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `@+id/something` and `@id/something` is that the first one is creating an id, and the second one is referencing an id that has already been created. The first time that you mention an id you have to create it using `@+id/`, and anything after that can use `@id/`.

When you give a view the attribute `android:id` you do not have to use `@+id/` if you have already used that somewhere earlier in your file.

Because of the way android compiles XML files, it reads your image view first, reaches the point where you write `@id/` searches for an id in the R file, and can't find it. But if you call `@+id/` the eclipse searches for the id in the R file, can't find it, and adds it.

Also, this is not specific to RelativeLayouts, if you put the same code in a linear layout, you would also get that error

Answer (score 0):

`@+id` instructs the parser to create the ID if it does not exist. `@id` is used to refer to an existing ID.